# Why is this List.Except so slow in some cases (and how to speed it up)?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I have the following two lists, which are pairs of strings.  One is what I expect and the other is what I found.  I want to find out what is missing.  The code works, but some cases are much, much slower than others.

- When n = 1, it takes 21 seconds for the `.Except()` call.
- When n = 10, it takes 2 seconds for the `.Except()` call.

In both cases, it is the same number of elements.  Is this just some hash table collisions? What can I do to make all cases equally quick?

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> FoundItems = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ExpectedItems = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

int n = 1;
for (int k1 = 0; k1 < n; k1 ++)
{
    for (int k2 = 0; k2 < 3500/n; k2++)
    {
        ExpectedItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>( k1.ToString(), k2.ToString()));
        if (k2 != 0)
        {
            FoundItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k1.ToString(), k2.ToString()));
        }
    }
}

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

//!!!! This is the slow line.
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> MissingItems = ExpectedItems.Except(FoundItems).ToList();
//!!!! 

string MatchingTime = "Matching Time: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " (" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000 + " sec)";
MessageBox.Show(MatchingTime + ", " + ExpectedItems.Count() + " items");
```

My data really are strings, I just use integers in this test case because it's easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I believe the problem is that `KeyValuePair` effectively only hashes on the first field (with some oddities - it's not *quite* as simple as that).

So for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ShowPairHash("a", "b");
        ShowPairHash("a", "c");
        ShowPairHash("Z", "0");
        ShowPairHash("Z", "1");
    }

    static void ShowPairHash(string x, string y)
    {
        var pair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x, y);
        Console.WriteLine(pair.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
733397256
733397256
733397325
733397325
```

So when `n = 1`, *all your items* have the same hash code... so everything needs to be checked for full equality on every addition to the `HashSet<T>` which is built inside `Except`.

If you change your `KeyValuePair` calls to

```
new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k2.ToString(), k1.ToString())
```

... then the n = 1 case is blindingly fast.

Better, though: use a type with a better hash code computation. For example, an anonymous type, or a `Tuple<string, string>`, or your own custom struct version of `Tuple<string, string>` (but implementing `IEquatable<T>`).